# AttributeError after some minor changes

Tags: python, class, sockets, send

I use socket. My client ofc uses it to send and receive data.
I created a file that contains a class that manages lists and who gets certain data.
It used to work perfectly... but now, even though I have access to the class, it tells me that the send() attribute from the socket module is not there.

AttributeError: 'ClientInstance' object has no attribute 'send'

How can it be that it does not understand this anymore?

I don't even know how to ask the right question in this regard.

This gitHub link contains the whole code. Maybe someone can tell me what is happening: https://github.com/smilefl0w/CallApplication

Answer (score 0):

the problem was that I added an instance to the self.paired list rather than the client-information; this happens in the search_handeling() on the server side.